# Converting Hex Dump to Double

Tags: c++, c, hex

MY program currently prints a hex dump by reading from memory where  a double is stored.

It gives me

00 00 00 00 00 50 6D 40

How can I make sense of this and get the value I store, which is 234.5?

I realize there are 64 bits in a double, first bit is the sign bit, the next 11 are exponent and the last 52 are the mantissa

(-1)^sign * (1.mantissa) * 2^(exponent - 1023)

However, I've tried both little endian and big endian representations of the double and I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Note: if the biased exponent is 0, the formula becomes `(-1)^sign * (0.mantissa) * 2^(1 - 1023)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to realize is that most modern processors use little endian representation. This means that the last byte is actually the most significant. So your value taken as a single hex constant is `0x406d500000000000`.

The sign bit is `0`. The next 11 bits are `0x406`. The next 52 are `0xd500000000000`.

`(-1)^sign` is `1`. `2^(exponent - 1023)` is `128`. Those are simple.

`1.mantissa` is hard to evaluate unless you realize what it really means. It's the constant `1.0` followed by the 52 bits of mantissa as a fraction. To convert from an integer to a fraction you need to divide it by the representation of 2^52. `0xd500000000000/(2**52)` is `0.83203125`.

Putting it all together: `1 * (1.0 + 0.83203125) * 128` is `234.5`.

Answer (score 0):

[This online calculator](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html) can do it for you.

If you are on big endianness, enter

```
00 00 00 00 00 50 6D 40
```

or if you are on little endianness

```
40 6D 50 00 00 00 00 00
```

The first is a strange number, the second is 234.5

Comment: Okay so using this calculator we see that the exponent is 1030

Comment: 1030 - 1023 is 7, we get 2^7 as the second part of the equation... but when we divide 234.5 by 2^7 we get a long number not equivalent to the mantissa shown in the calculator. I can't find out how to get the mantissa correctly